# Data do not persist to table in SQLite using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am using SQLite wrapper provided by http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com in VS2010

Here is the code that I am using

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

       INFO inf =  INFO.CreateINFO("test5", 123);
       TestDBEntities3 entity = new TestDBEntities3();
       entity.Connection.Open();
       entity.Connection.BeginTransaction();
       var result = from i in entity.INFOes
                    where i.Name.Equals(inf.Name)
                    select i;
       if (result.Count() == 0)
           entity.AddToINFOes(inf);
       entity.SaveChanges(true);
       entity.Connection.Close();
    }
```

When I execute the code data do not persist to the database. I am checking the right database mentioned in the connection string of App.config file.

Also I can re run the query without changing the primarykey data and no primary key conflict occurs.

But during the debug at line

```
entity.Connection.Close();
```

'entity' has the new created record in it but does not save.

Thanks

Comment: I removed the line entity.Connection.BeginTransaction(); and works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started transaction manually so you also have to commit it ...